# C# foreach loop - incrementing doesn't work with an Excel cell address

Tags: c#, excel, loops, foreach

I want to iterate through DataTable dt column names and save them in the exact same order in a fixed row in an Excel worksheet. All column names are logged (from first to last). However, only the last column name is actually written to Excel and it's in the cell where the first column should be.

```
foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
   int j = 0;
   j++;
   columnName = column.ToString();
   worksheet.Cells[5, j] = columnName;
   LogMessage(columnName);
}
```

What is wrong with this loop?

Comment: `int j = 0;` Move that to before the loop.

Comment: `j` will always be 1, since you set it to `0` each iteration and then increment it to `1`

Answer (score 1):

Each time you iterate, you set the value of j to 0 and then increment to 1. It will always be 1

```
int j = 0; // move this outside the for loop
foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {   
   j++;
...
```

Comment: Oh, it seems so obvious now, thanks for pointing it out!